# SAS RT and LT Mod

Tags: sas

I want to flag the claim when any claim has LT and RT modifier on the same date in the same claim to the same member.

I want to write SAS code.

for example

```
Mem_id clm_id   DOS      Mod1 Mod2  Mod3 Mod4 Flag
AA000  12345  1/1/2023     LT  59  
AA000  12345  1/1/2023     60  RT             LR_RT

BA000  11111  2/2/2023     T1  T6    RT  
BA000  11111  2/2/2023     60  LT             LR_RT

CA000  22222  3/3/2023     T1  T6    RT  
CA000  22222  3/3/2023     60  50         80  Okay

DA000  33333  4/4/2023     T1  AS    SX  
DA000  33333  4/4/2023     59  55         LT  Okay

EA000  44444  5/5/2023     T8  AB    SX  
EA000  44444  5/5/2023     59  69         UU  Okay
```

and other then any combination should come as 'Okay'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input Mem_id $ clm_id DOS :ddmmyy10. (Mod1 Mod2 Mod3 Mod4)($);
format DOS ddmmyy10.;
infile datalines missover;
datalines;
AA000 12345 1/1/2023 LT 59       
AA000 12345 1/1/2023 60 RT       
BA000 11111 2/2/2023 T1 T6 RT    
BA000 11111 2/2/2023 60 LT       
CA000 22222 3/3/2023 T1 T6 RT    
CA000 22222 3/3/2023 60 50 80    
DA000 33333 4/4/2023 T1 AS SX    
DA000 33333 4/4/2023 59 55 LT    
EA000 44444 5/5/2023 T8 AB SX    
EA000 44444 5/5/2023 59 69 UU    
;

proc sort data = have;
   by Mem_id clm_id DOS;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by Mem_id clm_id DOS;
   array m mod:;

   if first.clm_id then do;
      lt = 0; rt = 0;
   end;
    
   do over m;
      if m = 'LT' then lt = 1;
      if m = 'RT' then rt = 1;
   end; 

   if last.clm_id then do;
      if sum(lt, rt) = 2 then flag = 'LR_RT';
      else                    flag = 'Okay';
   end;

   retain lt rt;
   drop lt rt;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. This code works perfectly! A big Bravo to you :-)